# conditional include of .pri file Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qmake

I have this portion of code on a .pri file of my qt project:

```
contains(DEFINES, VIEWER_DEFINED){
    message("Viewer found")
    include ($$PWD/gui/dcelmanager.pri)
} else {
    message("Viewer not found")
}
```

if VIEWER_DEFIENED exists then "Viewer found" is printed, and if it doesn't exists, it prints "Viewer not found". So far so good.

However, in both cases dcel_manager.pri is being included.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This part of .pro file looks ok. May it be so you include your .pri also somewhere else in .pro?

Comment: No, because if I delete this part of code, dcelmanager.pri is not being included by qmake! Can it be a bug of qmake?

Comment: I found similar thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782060/qt-creator-and-conditional-build, it may be a feature of Qt Creator

Comment: qmake is run twice (or more, depending on your configuration) for debug and release. So if you remove the define from debug, that pri will still be included in release

Comment: @SebastianLange, I think you nailed it.

Comment: @demonplus sounds like a bug, not a feature :)

Comment: @SebastianLange then why only a message is being printed on my console?