# Why [SUBDIRS+=] always work int equals area?

Tags: qt, qmake

I use equals a value to add different subdirs, only sub1 will build. but why all subdirs will show in left projects view

```
TEMPLATE = subdirs
TEST_VALUE = 1

equals(TEST_VALUE,1) {
message($$TEST_VALUE)
SUBDIRS += \
    sub1
}

equals(TEST_VALUE,2) {
message($$TEST_VALUE)
SUBDIRS += \
    sub2
}

equals(TEST_VALUE,3) {
message($$TEST_VALUE)
    SUBDIRS += \
        sub3
}
```

[image]

I tried looking in the build directory and only sub1 was built, which is correct. Also printing the TEST_VALUE value inside the judgment, also only 1 was printed, which is also correct. But I still can't understand why the project view on the left shows all subdirs

Comment: Qt Creator doesn't consider it a bug but a feature. It shows the whole project tree instead of the "to be built" project tree.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Qt Creator and conditional build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782060/qt-creator-and-conditional-build)